# Overriding location-tracking in OSMdroid

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, android-location, osmdroid

I'm wondering how to override where OSMdroid derives its location from. In my app, I am already tracking and storing the user's location, so doing it twice (OSMdroid, and my app is redundant). Is it worth the effort in terms of battery-life to change the source of OSMdroid's location to my location-tracker? IF IT IS, does anyone have an insight into how I might do this. OSMdroid is currently added to my project via Gradle. Just trying to do some research before implementing it.

Comment: It's possible to override OSMdroid's location provider by having a class: `class FakeOsmdroidLocationProvider implements IMyLocationProvider {...}` and then use that in place of `IMyLocationProvider` when creating for example a `MyLocationNewOverlay`. It only brings benefit if you otherwise request locations very seldomly or only low accucary locations without GPS, or if you have some extra filtering for the location data in your code.

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for replying - doesn't seem too hard. I request location every two seconds or so at high accuracy. So I should probably override OSMdroid's location?

Comment: You keep the GPS hardware on anyway with your own code, so I don't think overriding OSMdroid's location provider would bring any power saving benefit. I did it because we already had location related code that does Kalman filtering.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for - thank you

Answer (score 1):

In osmdroid, you are not obliged to put a "MyLocationNewOverlay" on the map. In this case, osmdroid will do nothing about location.

If you still want a graphical representation on the map about your current location/orientation/precision, you can use a DirectedLocationOverlay. You will have to "refresh" it yourself - typically with your own tracking and storing code. 
Example [here](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMNavigator/src/main/java/com/osmnavigator/MapActivity.java).